# What is the closure of the Eilenberg-MacLane spectra under limits? under colimits?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy

Every bounded spectrum is in the closure of the Eilenberg MacLane spectra under finite co/limits. Thus every bounded below (resp. above) spectrum is in the closure of the EM spectra under limits (resp. colimits). Let $\mathcal L$ denote the closure of the EM spectra under limits, and let $\mathcal C$ denote the closure of the EM spectra under colimits.

Note that $\mathcal L$ is also closed under (infinite) products, and $\mathcal C$ is also closed under (infinite) coproducts.

**Question 1:** What is a good description of $\mathcal L$?

**Question 2:** What is a good description of $\mathcal C$?

**Question 3:** What is an example of a spectrum in $\mathcal L$ which is not a(n infinite) product of bounded-below spectra?

**Question 4:** What is an example of a spectrum in $\mathcal C$ which is not a(n infinite) sum of bounded-above spectra?

Comment: If you take infinite (co)product of Eilenberg-MacLane spectra with homotopy groups in different dimensions, you get examples for Questions 3 and 4, don't you?  Or C and L are closure under finite (co)limits?

Comment: @user43326 If $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb Z}$ are abelian groups, then $\oplus_{n \in \mathbb Z} \Sigma^n HA_n = \prod_{n \in \mathbb Z} \Sigma^n HA_n$ is both a product and a coproduct of EM spaces, and in particular of bounded spectra -- so it's not an example for (3) or (4).

Comment: I left a comment with a more detailed approach to #3 and #4, and then deleted it, since #3 and #4 are similar to homework questions I ask when I teach holims and hocolims in 2nd year courses in algebraic topology. But here's the hint I give to students, which works well for #3 and #4: _use the Bousfield-Kan spectral sequence._

Comment: @A.S. I did see your comment before you deleted it, and I'm confused -- if I take the constant $H \mathbb F_p$-valued functor $X \to Spectra$ for a space $X$, then the colimit is $\Sigma^\infty_+ X \wedge H\mathbb F_p$ which is generally not bounded above, but it's an $H \mathbb F_p$-module, and therefore it decomposes as a coproduct $\oplus_n \Sigma^n H\mathbb F_p^{\oplus d_n}$ of EM spectra, so I don't think it gives an example for (4). If we take the limit, we get $Hom(\Sigma^\infty_+ X,H\mathbb F_p)$, which is likewise an $H\mathbb F_p$-module, so I don't think we get an example for (3).

Comment: Yes, I didn't write a full solution, only what to consider that leads to a nice solution.

Comment: @A.S. The Bousfield-Kan spectral sequence is a general tool for computing the homotopy groups of a homotopy limit, so all I'm getting out of your hint to _use the Bousfield-Kan spectral sequence_ is that _I should compute the homotopy groups of some homotopy limit_, which isn't news to me... The specific limit you suggested computing in your deleted comment doesn't work. So I really don't know what you're driving at, and I'd appreciate it if you could be less cryptic.

Comment: Really, the issue for me is that I'm having trouble even thinking of e.g. a _map_ between products of bounded-below spectra which is not a product of maps between bounded-below spectra (if I could do that, I'd try taking the fiber of said map). So my issue right now is not an issue of not having computational tools at my disposal, but rather of even knowing what to feed into said computational tools.

Comment: @TimCampion I don't get it.  We have $\pi _i (\oplus _n \Sigma nHA_n)=A_i$, so if all $A_i$'s are non-zero, this is neither bounded below or above.

Comment: @user43326 Right, but in (3) for example, I specifically asked for something which is not a _product_ of bounded-below spectra, and $\oplus_n \Sigma^n HA_n = \prod_n \Sigma^n HA_n$ is explicitly a product of bounded-below spectra.

Comment: Sorry,  somehow I had read "which is not bounded-below"...  My mistake.

Answer (score 6):

This is an answer to Questions 3 and 4. Consider the map

$$ H\mathbb Z/2 \xrightarrow{\ldots, Sq^{2^n},\ldots} \prod_{n=1}^\infty \Sigma^{2^n} H\mathbb Z/2.$$

This is a map to a product, where the $n$-th component is the map $Sq^{2^n}\colon H\mathbb Z/2 \to \Sigma^{2^n} H\mathbb Z/2.$ This is a map between products of bounded-above spectra which is not a product of maps between bounded-above spectra. As you suggested in a comment, I believe that the cofiber of this map is an element of $\mathcal C$ that is not a direct sum of bounded above spectra.

It is enough to prove that the fiber of this map is not a direct sum of bounded above spectra. Let $F$ be the fiber. Moreover, for all $m\ge 0$ let $F_m$ be the fiber of the map
$$ H\mathbb Z/2 \xrightarrow{\ldots, Sq^{2^n},\ldots} \prod_{n=1}^m \Sigma^{2^n} H\mathbb Z/2.$$
There is a tower of spectra
$$\cdots F_m \to F_{m-1}\to \cdots $$
and $F$ is the homotopy limit of this tower.

We want to prove that $F$ is not equivalent to a sum of bounded above spectra. I claim that it is enough to prove that none of the maps $F_m\to F_{m-1}$ has a homotopy section. To prove the claim, notice that $F_m$ is the $2^m-1$-th Postnikov section of $F$.
Suppose $F$ splits as a sum (or equivalently a product) of bounded above spectra. Then each Postnikov section of $F$ admits a corresponding splitting of Postnikov sections of factors.

Among the putative factors of $F$ there is one factor, let's call it $X$, that satisfies $\pi_0(X)\cong \mathbb Z/2$. All other factors have $\pi_0=0$. $X$ is bounded above. Let $m$ be the smallest positive integer such that $\pi_{2^m-1}(X)=0$. We have a splitting $F\simeq X\times Y$ for some spectrum $Y$. It induces a splitting of Postnikov sections
$$P_{2^m-1} F\simeq P_{2^m-1}X\times P_{2^m-1}Y.$$

But by our construction, $P_{2^m-1} F=F_m$, $P_{2^m-1}X\simeq F_{m-1}$, and $P_{2^m-1}Y\simeq \Sigma^{2^m-1} H\mathbb Z/2$. It follows that the map $F_m\to F_{m-1}$ has a section.

It remains to prove that none of the maps $F_m\to F_{m-1}$ has a homotopy section. The spectrum $F_m$ is the total fiber of the following square
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
H\mathbb Z/2 & \xrightarrow{\ldots, Sq^{2^n}, \ldots} & \prod_{n=1}^{m-1} \Sigma^{2^n} H\mathbb Z/2\\
\quad \quad \downarrow Sq^{2^m} & & \downarrow \\
\Sigma^{2^m} H\mathbb Z/2 & \to & *
\end{array}
$$
Note that the fiber of the top map is $F_{m-1}$. There is a fibration sequence
$$F_m \to F_{m-1} \to \Sigma^{2^m} H\mathbb Z/2$$
where the second map is a composition
$$F_{m-1}\to H\mathbb Z/2\xrightarrow{Sq^{2^m}} \Sigma^{2^m}H\mathbb Z/2.$$
If the map $F_m\to F_{m-1}$ has a section, then this composition is null.
But this is not possible, because the kernel of the homomorphism of graded groups
$$\mathcal A\cong [H\mathbb Z/2, H\mathbb Z/2]_*\to [F_{m-1}, H\mathbb Z/2]_*$$
is the left ideal generated by $Sq^2, Sq^4, \ldots, Sq^{2^{m-1}}$, and it does not contain $Sq^{2^m}$.

A context where such a spectrum occurs more or less naturally is the Adams spectal sequence, which in some incarnation probably can be called the Bousfield-Kan spectral sequence. Consider the cobar construction that gives rise to the ASS:
$$H\mathbb Z/2 \Rightarrow H\mathbb Z/2\wedge H\mathbb Z/2 \Rightarrow \cdots H\mathbb Z/2^{\wedge k+1} \cdots$$
(I did not typeset the arrows properly, but it is supposed to be a cosimplicial object in spectra). The second stage of the Tot tower can be identified with the homotopy fiber of a map
$$H\mathbb Z/2 \to H\mathbb Z/2 \wedge \overline{H\mathbb Z/2}$$
where $\overline{H\mathbb Z/2}$ is the cofiber of the map $S\to H\mathbb Z/2$. The spectrum $H\mathbb Z/2 \wedge \overline{H\mathbb Z/2}$ splits as a product of Eilenberg - Mac Lane spectra, and I believe the fiber of the map above is an example of a spectrum in $\mathcal C$ that is not a sum of bounded above spectra. Maybe A.S. had in mind something like this in their comment, but this is just a guess.

Dually, you can construct a spectrum that is in $\mathcal L$ but is not a product of bounded below spectra by taking the fiber of the map
$$\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty \Sigma^{-2^n} H\mathbb Z/2 \xrightarrow{\ldots, Sq^{2^n}, \ldots} H\mathbb Z/2.$$

Comment: Thanks! I was initially confused because the map $H\mathbb F_2 \xrightarrow{(Sq^{2^n})_n} \prod_n \Sigma^{2^n} H\mathbb F_2$ is a map between bounded-below spectra, and as such its co/fiber is also bounded-below. But your point is that $\prod_n \Sigma^{2^n} H \mathbb F_2 = \oplus_n \Sigma^{2^n} H \mathbb F_2$, so we equally have a map between coproducts of bounded-above spectra, and your point is that the cofiber is not a coproduct of bounded-above spectra. I find this quite plausible -- but I don't see why it suffices to show that the maps $F_m \to F_{m-1}$ don't split?

Comment: Added an argument for that.